# BackboneJS + Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js

Does anyone know how to use Backbone together with Codeigniter? I have an MVC-Framework (Codeigniter) what does the server side stuff. But for frontend we want to use the backbone framework.

So my CI structure is the classic one:

```
 [application]
 [assets]
 [system]
 index.php
```

so, how do I integrate Backbone? is there some best practice?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to create a folder structure like this:

- application
- assets
- system
- html

  - js

    - app
    - libraries
  - css

And keep Backbone app inside the *app* folder.